# Regular expression - extract a substring

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like,

`"{'Name':'AllSecurityUpdates-Today' , 'Value':'test'}"`

I want to extract the values for `Name` as `AllSecurityUpdates-Today` and for `Value` as `test`. Please help me with a regular expression for same.

Answer (score 3):

Bro
for that case in javascript and c# use **JSON** not regex.

javascript:

```
var a = {Name:'AllSecurityUpdates-Today', Value:'test'};
var name = a.Name;
var val = a.Value;
```

c#:

Create a object with property Name and Value

```
var a = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<YourObject>("{'Name':'AllSecurityUpdates-Today' , 'Value':'test'}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            string input = "{'Name':'AllSecurityUpdates-Today' , 'Value':'test'}";
            string pattern = @":\'(?'name'[^\']+)[^\:]+:\'(?'value'[^\']+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Value = {1}", match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

c# code

```
private static string ExtractJist(string freeText)
{
StringBuilder patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
patternBuilder.Append(@"Name: (?<name>.*$)\n").Append("Value: (?<value>.*$)\n");
Match match = Regex.Match(freeText, patternBuilder.ToString(), RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string name= match.Groups["name"].ToString();
string value= match.Groups["value"].ToString();
return string.Concat(name, "|", value);
}
```

Call the method as follows:

```
string source = @"name: AllSecurityUpdates-Today
value: test";
string extracted = ExtractJist(source);
```